# Adding fade out/in to flame img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 images(with 2 states red(on) and grey(off), 3 are clickable and the middle flame isn't. The flame is turned off when 1/2 or 3 of the outer images are clicked. If so the flame is turned off, if they're all on the flame is on.

I want to add a fade in/out to the flame when it changes state/image.

Code : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Qt74ByrQ)!

Greetings,
Tomas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var $FlameCounter = 3;
        var FlameImg = document.getElementById('Flame');
        var self = this;

        function SetFlame(){
        if($FlameCounter ==3){

                $(FlameImg).attr('src', '../Images/_Flame.png');   
                }
                else{
                    $(FlameImg).attr('src', '../Images/_Flame2.png');  
                }
            }



        var $ClickToLe = $('.TopLeft').click(function () {
            var self = this;

            if ($(self).attr('src') == "../Images/_TopLeft.png") { // Rood
                $(self).attr('src', '../Images/_TopLeft2.png');


                $FlameCounter -=1;
            } else {
                $(self).attr('src', '../Images/_TopLeft.png'); // Rood
                $(FlameImg).attr('src', '../Images/_Flame.png');

                $FlameCounter +=1;
            }

                SetFlame();
        });



        var $ClickToRi = $('.TopRight').click(function () {
            var self = this;

            if ($(this).attr('src') == "../Images/_TopRight.png"){ //Grijs
                $(this).attr('src', '../Images/_TopRight2.png');


                $FlameCounter -=1;
            } else {
                $(this).attr('src', '../Images/_TopRight.png'); //Rood
                $(FlameImg).attr('src', '../Images/_Flame.png');

                $FlameCounter +=1;
            }
            SetFlame();
        });

        var $ClickToBot = $('.Bottom').click(function () {
            var self = this;

            if ($(this).attr('src') == "../Images/_Bottom.png"){
                $(this).attr('src', '../Images/_Bottom2.png');


                $FlameCounter -=1;
            } else {
                $(this).attr('src', '../Images/_Bottom.png');
                $(FlameImg).attr('src', '../Images/_Flame.png');

                $FlameCounter +=1;
            }
            SetFlame();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please check: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tried to improve it, it's quite difficult.

Comment: Can you post your  code here please?

Comment: Posted the code as well.